# Head content appears in the body tag (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html

My head content(metas, scripts etc.) appears in the body tag.   I have header php with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

  <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width">
    <title<?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?> 
  </head>

<header class="header">
  <h1 id="logo"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">|||</a></h1>
  <h4 id='title' ><?php the_title();  ?></h4>
</header>

<body>
```

and footer.php is closing it with this. `

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>`
```

Already tried changing encoding from UTF-8 to UTF-8 without BOM using Notepad++, and still the same ,, this is my website if you wanna see with inspect [website]

[website](http://arnoldpiscel.com) . Any ideas ? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is broken:

```
<title> Name Lastname / Official Website</title>
      ^---- missing >
```

Comment: THANKS !  Have not noticed this.. sorry for the question GUYS xD

Comment: when in doubt, run the html through the w3c validator. it'll find that sort of problem pretty much instantly.

Comment: checked, edited ^_^ thanks a lot for information and help !